# pandas: conditionally select a row cell for each column based on a mask

Tags: pandas, numpy, conditional-statements, mask

I want to be able to extract values from a pandas dataframe using a mask. However, after searching around, I cannot find a solution to my problem.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2, size=(2,10)))
mask = np.random.randint(0,2, size=(1,10))
```

I basically want the mask to serve as a index lookup for each column.

So if the mask was [0,1] for columns [a,b], I want to return:

`df.iloc[0,a], df.iloc[1,b]`

but in a pythonic way.

I have tried e.g.:

```
df.apply(lambda x: df.iloc[mask[x], x] for x in range(len(mask)))
```

which gives a Type error that I don't understand.

A for loop can work but is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With NumPy, that's covered as [`advanced-indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) and should be pretty efficient -

```
df.values[mask, np.arange(mask.size)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [59]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(11,99, size=(5,10)))

In [60]: mask = np.random.randint(0,5, size=(1,10))

In [61]: df
Out[61]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0  17  87  73  98  32  37  61  58  35  87
1  52  64  17  79  20  19  89  88  19  24
2  50  33  41  75  19  77  15  59  84  86
3  69  13  88  78  46  76  33  79  27  22
4  80  64  17  95  49  16  87  82  60  19

In [62]: mask
Out[62]: array([[2, 3, 0, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0]])

In [63]: df.values[mask, np.arange(mask.size)]
Out[63]: array([[50, 13, 73, 95, 19, 77, 87, 58, 35, 87]])
```